# XLSX file getting corrupted when trying to write data into multiple sheets in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm new to JAVA. I have a requirement to load multiple files in a specific folder into an excel xlsx (not xls file because the input files have more than 65k records) file different sheets. Below is the code that I wrote. The xlsx file is getting corrupted, it is not opening. Can you please help?

```
      public class twotxttoxlsx{
             public static void main(String[]args){
             try{

               File folder = new File("C:/txttoxls/");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                  XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();

            for (File file : listOfFiles) {


   if (file.isFile()) {

       String thisline;
       ArrayList<String> al = null;
       ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

       XSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());  
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           System.out.println("Got here");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

           while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
               al = new ArrayList<String>();
               String strar[] = thisline.split("#");

               for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) { 
                   for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {

                       ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                       XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);


                       for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                           XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                           cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                       }
                   }

                   al.add(strar[j]);

               } 

             arlist.add(al);
           }

           fis.close();  
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/txttoxls/Test.xlsx");
           workbook.write(fileOut);
           fileOut.flush();
           fileOut.close();
           br.close();
   }
   }

           System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

            } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                 System.out.println(ex);

                }
                }
  }
```

Edited on 4/27: working code but performance issue exists.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList; 
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;


public class createXLSXfileTest{
public static void main(String[]args){

    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("sheet1");  
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("Sheet2");
    try{

           File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/file1.txt");

          FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/test.xlsx");

      if (file.isFile()) {

       String thisline;
       ArrayList<String> al = null;
       ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           System.out.println("loading 1st file");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

           while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
               al = new ArrayList<String>();
               String strar[] = thisline.split("#");

               for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) { 
                   for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {

                       ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                       XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);


                       for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                           XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                           cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                       }
                   }

                   al.add(strar[j]);

               } 

             arlist.add(al);
           }

           fis.close();  

      }
      File file1 = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/file2.txt");
      if (file1.isFile()) {

          String thisline;
          ArrayList<String> al = null;
          ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
              System.out.println("loading 2nd file");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

              while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  al = new ArrayList<String>();
                  String strar[] = thisline.split("#");

                  for (int j = 0; j < strar.length; j++) { 
                      for (int k = 0; k < arlist.size(); k++) {

                          ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                          XSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow((short) k);


                          for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                              XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                              cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                          }
                      }

                      al.add(strar[j]);

                  } 

                arlist.add(al);
              }

              fis.close();  
                             workbook.write(fileOut);
              fileOut.flush();
              fileOut.close();
              br.close();


      System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");


   }} catch ( Exception ex ) {
   System.out.println(ex);

  }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Is any exception thrown that you are not showing here?

Comment: No I don't. It runs fine without any error, and even generates the file. But it is corrupted. If I don't have multiple files in my input folder, that means with one input file it creates xlsx file with no issues.

Comment: I miss `workbook.close()` whereas the fileOut.flush and close are not needed.

Comment: How many rows are you trying to store in the file in total? How many tabs are you generating? What's the final size of the generated XLSX? Does it work when you generate an xlsx for a single file? Does it work for 2 files? If it does then try to generate a separate xlsx file with each iteration `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/txttoxls/Test" + introducedFileIndex + ".xlsx");` - as you're adding sheet each time you'll be able to see where it starts breaking.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see is that your sheet name could possibly be a problem.

`XSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());`

Excel sheet names are extremely restrictive. Maximum length 31, and many special characters are not allowed, including `/[]:\?` and many more. Consider writing a "toWorksheetName" function to clean the filename up into a legal sheet name.

Another thing you can try is to attempt to read the XLS with POI. That might help narrow down the problem. [Help is here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/), under "Working with .xlsx files".

On a side note: You do not need to close `fis`; closing `br` is enough. Close() is passed down from the decorator to the wrapped streams. This won't break anything though.

Comment: _Excel sheet names are extremely restrictive. Maximum length 31_ Sounds like that 4.30 AM empirical discovery that made you go ``ah!''.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Finally i got my code working to generate xlsx file with separate tabs for each input file.But I'm facing performance issues with my actual files since one of the input file has around 300k records. And it is running forever. Can you please help me rewrite the code to improve performance. I have added the working code to my original post.

Comment: Couple thoughts here. (1) get rid of arlist & read each row directly from strar. this will save a ton of memory and pointless copying. (2) Move main into a method like createXLSXfile(String filename), then create each XLSX file on a different thread in a thread pool of around 5-10. This might speed things up around 8x. (3) Use VBA instead of Java.